# unprofessional and totally unacceptable greetings

Tags: slang

Is greeting someone as "Hi there John, " considered unprofessional and in no uncertain terms considered totally unacceptable when greeting work collegues?

Comment: There's some rather emotionally loaded language in here that is pretty baffling and sounds an awful lot like there's context to this question that isn't available. You should consider [edit]ing out the bit about "in no uncertain terms considered totally unacceptable", or else if it's crucial to the question, explain why you're asking about that unusually strong criterion in the first place.

Comment: A remark such as “Hi there, John” sounds cordial, not unprofessional. I agree with the previous comment – you should add some information about **why** you think a perfectly normal conversational greeting seems “totally unacceptable” in the workplace. I can’t tell if you’re bothered by the informality of the word “Hi” (vs. “Hello”), or the use of a first name in the greeting (i.e, “John” instead of, say, “Mr Smith”).

Answer (score 1):

Modes of address employed with colleagues vary in different cultures. I work in the UK Government service (the "Civil Service") in a financial/legal role. The convention is that all staff from lowest to highest are on first name ("Hi, John") terms. This informality and freedom from ritual deference is considered a very important part of our "values" which include treating all colleagues with respect and valuing their contributions. Respect shown to more senior colleagues would consist of things like paying attention to instructions and carrying them out promptly and thoroughly, even if they are phrased as friendly requests. Respect would also require that bad or incomplete instructions are questioned and clarified by the person being asked to carry them out. In France, workplace etiquette is much more formal; people are more often addressed by title and surname.